# Populate unpopulated reaction.users

Tags: node.js, discord.js

On a `messageReactionAdd` event, one of the parameters is a `MessageReaction`. From that reaction, I do `message.reaction` to find the message that the reaction is from. I want to use that message to find all the reactions that the parameters `user` has reacted to on that message.

However, one obstacle is that when the bot restarts, it seems as though the `message.reactions` is not fully populated, and the data needs to be fetched. I need the users of a looped reaction, but I'm struggling on that part.

I have tried:

```
await message.reactions.reduce((p, c) => c.fetchUsers(), 0);
// I had thought this would of cached the users of every reaction on the message, but that did not work.
// next

message.reactions.forEach((x, y) => {
  x.fetchUsers();
});
// this was also the same train of thought, but still to no avail.
```

What I mean by that users are not in the `message.reaction.users` object, I mean this:

```
// the bot restarts - and a reaction is added
console.log(reaction.users);
// outputs: Collection [Map] {}
// this is supposed to be populated with many users, but it's empty
// however, if I add ANY reaction again, not doing anything else
// it outputs a Collection with many users in it, which is expected
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Edit: relevant code

```
// raw.js (the raw event)
const events = {
  MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD: 'messageReactionAdd',
};
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (client, event) => {
  if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;
  const { d: data } = event;
  const user = client.users.get(data.user_id);
  if (!user) return;
  const channel = client.channels.get(data.channel_id);
  if (!channel) return;

  if (channel.messages.has(data.message_id)) return;
  const message = await channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);
  const emojiKey = (data.emoji.id) ? `${data.emoji.name}:${data.emoji.id}` : data.emoji.name;

  let reaction = message.reactions.get(emojiKey);
  if (!reaction) {
    const emoji = new Discord.Emoji(client.guilds.get(data.guild_id), data.emoji);
    reaction = new Discord.MessageReaction(message, emoji, 1, data.user_id === client.user.id);
  }

  client.emit(events[event.t], reaction, user);
};

// messageReactionAdd.js (the messageReactionAdd event)
module.exports = async (client, reaction, user) => {
  const message = reaction.message;
  if (!message)
    return;
  //await message.reactions.reduce((p, c) => c.fetchUsers(), 0);
  message.reactions.forEach((x,y) => {
    x.fetchUsers();
  });
  reactions = await message.reactions.filter(r => r.users.has(`${user.id}`));
  console.log(reactions);
};
```

Comment: When you achieve the intended result, are you reacting on a message sent *after* the client restarts?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `when you achieve the intended result`?

Comment: When `reaction.users` is populated?

Comment: If I send the message, and the client does not restart, and I add a reaction, the users is populated.  
However, the client starts after the message is sent, the users is not populated unless I add the same or any reaction twice.  
I want to make it so if the client restarts after the message is sent, it does not need two reactions to be added before I can use the users of the messages reactions.

Comment: Most likely caused by the fact that the message isn't cached. What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I am using 11.4.2. I am using a raw event to then emit the messageReactionAdd event if that makes a difference.

Comment: Mind showing all of your (relevant) code?

Comment: I have added relevant code into the post. @slothiful

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the problem I had, sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Mind posting the answer? It may help other people experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code is what fixed this problem for me.

```
// raw.js event file
  await reaction.message.reactions.forEach(r => {
    r.fetchUsers({before: `${reaction.message.author.id}`});
  });
  // emit the messageReactionAdd event

// messageReactionAdd.js event file
  // the message.reactions.users should be populated, which I can use
  reactions = await reaction.message.reactions.filter(r => r.users.has(`${reaction.message.author.id}`));
```

I had used this code in the wrong events which made no logical sense which made the results that I had thought was invalid.